# Explaining big amount withdrawal in UK visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm in the process of submitting a UK visitor's visa, and I'm wondering if I need to explain and backup with evidence a significant, large withdrawal from my active account? Or would that only apply for funds?

Comment: There’s nothing in the guidance to say you need to explain spending your own money https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf#page24 *But* eg if the funds weren’t in your account for long and/or the withdrawal materially affects your overall personal circumstances, I would err on the side of caution and explain. Also, since you feel the need to ask this question, you are obviously doubtful. I would therefore consider how you’d feel if you *don’t* explain and you get a refusal.

Comment: If you do not tell them and get rejected you are going to die wondering what would have happened if you had told them the truth, the whole truth, ...